# Shorten all value labels of a variable

Tags: stata

Let's say I'm using

```
sysuse auto
```

where the variable foreign has two value labels. I want to take a certain variable, `foreign`, and change all the value labels that are longer than 6 chars, to 3 chars + `(...)`.

In this dataset, that would mean changing the labels to `For(...)` and `Dom(...)`. In my actual dataset, I have dozens of different values. Therefore, I'm looking for a solution that loops through all value labels, and doesn't specifically change each of these two manually.

Since I'm doing this on an air gap server, I prefer approaches that work with default packages.

Comment: Updated my answer to do it without `elabel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sysuse auto, clear
levelsof foreign, local(values)
foreach value of local values {
    local labfull : label (foreign) `value'
    if strlen("`labfull'") > 6 {
        local labsub = substr("`labfull'", 1, 3)
        local newlab `"`labsub'(...)"'
        label define newlabel `value' "`newlab'", add
    }
    else label define newlabel `value' "`labfull'", add
}

label list
label values foreign newlabel
```